# Finding existing ShiroRoles to add to a New ShiroUser using Grails?

Tags: java, authentication, grails, shiro

How can I retrieve an existing ShiroRole that I've already created and stored in the database?

I've noticed that you can retrieve an existing ShiroUser by calling ShiroUser.findByUserName("somename") but I haven't found a method in ShiroRole that appears to do the same in finding the role by name.

I'm using the [Apache Shiro Grails Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/shiro)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Shiro Grails Plugin and the ShiroRole that it installs by default, it's really just a standard Grails domain class, so you should be able to do `ShiroRole.findByName('roleName')`.